# Github private linux server: Gives error when pushing master

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Sorry if I can't explain what is going on because I don't know whats going on. Everytime I try to push the master branch to my server it gives me this error message.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between the remote master branch and your local master branch, usually caused by a change pushed to the remote before your current HEAD change.

Example:

- Remote and you both have change ID `1abcde`.
- Someone commits `2ef1234` (which has a parent of `1abcde`) and pushes it.
- Remote HEAD is now `2ef1234`.
- You commit `356789a` with a parent of `1abcde` (because you haven't pulled). Your local HEAD is now `356789a`.
- You try to push `356789a` to the remote.
- You get this error, because it's trying to make a history of `1abcde->356789a` but there's already a history of `1abcde->2ef1234`.

Solution: do a `git pull` like it says (or use Sourcetree's Sync function since you tagged this with Sourcetree as well, see the docs at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing for more) and then push again.

If you do a pull, git can then correctly build a history that looks like `1abcde->2ef1234->356789a` since it has your changes as well as the remote changes and can line them up properly. However, note that if the remote change has edited a file you have edited, you now have a merge conflict and must resolve it accordingly.